# curl .gz file and pipe it for decompression

Tags: bash, scripts, curl, pipe, gzip

I am trying to download some `.gz` files (N.B. not `.tar.gz` ones) from given URLs and decompress them to overwrite existing files, if any.

For each individual download, I tried the following:

```
curl -O $URL | gunzip -f
```

However, this did not work as it failed with: `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`. I ran a series of this command inside a bash shell script.

If I spilt the command into two explicit steps, i.e. first download the file, and then decompress the `.gz` file, it works.

Why the piped version does not work?

Comment: Are you sure that `curl -O` actually streams the file to standard output? Perhaps you are thinking of `wget -O-`?

Comment: @steeldriver you should post that as an answer curl | tar xz ...

Comment: There is also `--compressed`, but this works only for a compressed responses.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A pipe (represented by the `|` symbol) sends the *standard output* of one process to the *standard input* of another. In your case, you appear to want to use a named file so a pipe is not appropriate - specifically, there is nothing to pipe (hence the `gunzip` error) because the remote contents are going to a local file. Instead, you'd need to extract the name of the file - for example, from its URL - something like (using bash's built in string manipulation capabilities)

```
curl -O "$URL" && gunzip -f "${URL##*/}"
```

If you want to use a pipe, then the way to do it would be something like

```
curl "$URL" | gunzip -c
```

(without the `-O` option) so that `curl` streams the remote contents to `stdout` from where it can be piped into `gunzip`, but then you would need to redirect the `gunzip` output to overwrite the target uncompressed file as appropriate.

Comment: the second one just dumps a bunch of binary data in your terminal. Thats exacty why I ended searching and found your answer. You should fix that or remove the part.

Answer (score 9):

Follow redirects when downloading.  Sometimes a web server has hidden redirects for security and/or random reasons.  If you don't follow the redirect, the wrong data gets downloaded and your application reading the piped data gets confused.  You can follow redirects with curl using the -L flag.

```
curl -L https://example.com/mygzip.tar.gz | tar zxv
```

Answer (score 0):

The below does 3 things

```
    mkdir -p ${DIR} && curl -L http://apachemirror.wuchna.com/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz | tar zxv -C ${DIR} --strip-components 1
```

1. Force creates the destination directory
2. UnArchives the archive to the given directory
3. Replaces the root directory with the given directory name by simply stripping down the archive's root directory.